# Simple Present, Simple Past or Past perfect progressive?

Tags: grammar, present-tense, simple-past, progressive-aspect, past-vs-present

Suppose if there's a web site which was out of service yesterday. And it's still down today. Which sentence below should I tell the web master?

1. The web site is down/(out of service) since yesterday.
2. The web site has been down/(out of service) since yesterday.

Comment: It's a bit different because what I'm using here is an adjective clause whereas the one you mentioned is about using verbs, active/passive voices.

Comment: Of these, choose the second.

Comment: @Lawrence It's not necessarily so. If the site is still down at the present moment, you really don't need to use the present perfect.

Comment: I understand your point. If you search with "present, present perfect", you will see a lot of excellent answers.

Comment: @Rathony The first sentence is awkward because *is* doesn't agree with *since yesterday*.

Comment: The website went down yesterday and has been down since. One of the most important functions of a website is to be up. Sadly, that function is not currently being performed.

Comment: Shouldn't this be likewise another speaking manner `The website is down, it has been out of service since yesterday` ? Anyway, thank @Lawrence and @Ricky, your comments really help.